# What are the physical limits of JMeter?

Tags: php, multithreading, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm working on a web application written in PHP which will be used by millions of visitors which can create many hits from different IP addresses all at the same time.  Potentially many thousands of hits in the same second is a very real possibility with this particular application.  Optimization is out of the question in regards to that fact.

That said, I've been doing some research into JMeter for stress testing.  My understanding is this uses multithreading to simulate many http requests (or other types of requests) to a designated server.

My thinking then is that you can only do so many parallel requests at once on a computer with a tool such as this, and I'm worried if I invest the time into learning JMeter further that it will not be enough of an accurate test for the website/service when it goes live.

That said after some looking around and not finding the answer, what are the physical limits of testing for JMeter? What kind of load can it accurately test? Are there alternatives to JMeter (like Grinder), or a service (paid or free) that simulates many different IP Addresses connecting to a server to test?

Comment: If you give a downvote please give an explanation why? I believe this is a legitimate question since I actively tried to find other solutions and answers to this concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The limits on the number of virtual users (threads) are very high (> two billion threads) so it is the last thing I would worry about especially given JMeter can be run in [Distributed Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
2. When it comes to web applications performance testing well-behaved JMeter test plan accurately simulates real users sitting behind real browser. What these "users" will do it totally up to you. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) guide for more details.
3. If you need the load to originate from different IPs (you know about [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) already, don't you?) be aware that JMeter is capable of [IP Spoofing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)
4. Alternatives are (apart from aforementioned Grinder)

   - [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
   - [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
   - [Locust](http://locust.io/)
   - [and many others](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview)

   However I believe JMeter is easier to learn, has better documentation and larger community

Comment: If JMeter can handle 2 billion threads, coudn't it single handely do dDos attacks from one machine?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but machine has to be **very** powerful. However I bet your single IP will simply be banner in first few seconds.

Comment: Interesting, but as long as I don't ban the IP address it can essentially be good enough for testing is the idea.

Comment: What software, can block the IP address when it connects to one after another quickly? (or at least what you recommend in anycase)

Comment: This is totally out of the original question scope, take a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Denial_of_Service_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks for this that really helped.