# How to tell if I'm hitting the limits of Jmeter & my hardware?

Tags: jmeter

I have seen some questions about the limits of jmeter, like "[What is the highest number of threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i/11922239#comment1968825_765101)" and "[What are the physical limits of jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092742/what-are-the-physical-limits-of-jmeter)". As [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765101/what-is-the-highest-number-of-threads-that-is-reasonable-to-simultaneously-run-i/11922239#comment1968825_765101) indicate, there's no specific limit to jmeter, but rather to jmeter configurations used on specific hardware setups. However, folks do indicate there's a limit & give tips on how to optimize.

My question is more basic - "how can I tell if I'm hitting the limits of my client (Jmeter + hardware)?"

I'm not talking about OOM errors (like described in this [blog post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-maximum-concurrent-users)), which are pretty obvious, but rather if jmeter is lagging. In the aggregate report, I can see [throughput](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report), and I could also count number of responses received in csv output & divide by time. Should I just check if that's equal to my desired QPS? Achieving a desired QPS in jmeter generally seems trickier than just blasting the server with users though, and the math from number of users -> QPS seems a bit tricky.

Finally, how can I tell if it's my server lagging or jmeter lagging? I'm wondering if I can test with some simple static webpage first to confirm jmeter's behavior, and then test my actual server. Any recommendations for a simple static page that can take a high amount of QPS?

Apologies if that's too many questions, but feel free to ask for more details or only answer the primary "how to tell if I'm hitting limits" question.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't have many "limits", at least they're too high to worry about, you can kick off as many as [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) threads given the underlying hardware/OS allows it and JMeter is properly configured

The easiest solution is switching to [Distributed Mode of JMeter execution](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter), i.e. if you're "hitting the limits of JMeter" when you add another instance of JMeter as an extra load generator the throughput should go up given the server is capable of handling the load.

Another option is first of all making sure that you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and setting up monitoring of baseline resources usage like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. on the machine where JMeter is running, if any of monitored metrics exceeds i.e. 90% of maximum available capacity - you're "hitting the limits" of the machine where JMeter is running.

Comment: I'm well aware that jmeter itself has no particular limit (and linked to questions asking that). I've updated the question to be more specific to my client's setup. I also agree that using jmeter remote execution is a good idea, but I want to confirm I need the additional complexity & hardware cost before using it (or while choosing a low but sufficient number of machines).

Thanks for the suggestion about monitoring CPU / RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm my setup worked by checking the [Aggregate Report's](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) throughput metric reached my desired QPS. Initially, when I did not reach the desired throughput and was testing against my server, I was not able to confirm whether the problem was my server or my load testing setup.

To confirm the load testing worked, I swapped the load test to hit a very simple 'hello world' service with an excess of resources. Here, the desired throughput was met.

For reference on actual setup, I ran jmeter on a [5.2xlarge EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-compute-intensive-c5-instances-for-amazon-ec2/) which had 8vCPUs, up to 10Gbps network bandwidth, and 16GiB of RAM and reached 1K QPS. I have yet to see how much further I can push this particular setup.